# How to force an attachment if 'Attached Bid'=TRUE?

Tags: trigger, attachment

I need to force users to include an attachment if a field called 'Attached Bid' on a custom object is equal to true. No attachment is necessary if =false.

I'm understanding that I'll need a trigger to do this, but I'm a little lost as to the 'how'...?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds as if you need to have salesforce check whether there is at least 1 attachment if the parent record (custom object) was saved and has a value of Attached_bid__c == true.  Your logic will need to exclude custom object records being inserted, and only focus on those updates -- since you cannot load a related attachment to a record that does not yet exist.

If this is the case, the I recommend the following

1. Create another custom field called `Has_Attachment__c`
2. On custom object create Validation rule to check whether a bid is requested and the record is being modified, but does not yet have an attachment.  The rule should state something like:

   AND (

   NOT(IsNew()),

   Attached_Bid__c = TRUE,

   Has_Attachment__c = FALSE

   )
3. Write a Trigger on Attachment (*before insert*) for records which are related to your custom object.  This trigger, for each attachment, will update the parent custom object field `Has_Attachment__c` to `TRUE` if the attachments are related to your custmo object.

After the attachment has been loaded, users should now be able to continue with making updates, logging activities, etc. since the validation rule in item 2 is now satisfied.